# How do I filter files by name when unzipping with FastZip?

Tags: fastzip

I am using FastZip to unzip some files. Some of these files have this string of characters in their name: "-submissions-". I want to filter those out so they do NOT get added to my folder of unzipped files. I have scoured the internet for a solution, but could not find any. Is there a way to do this with FastZip?

Answer (score 1):

FastZip's built-in filtering mainly focuses on including files rather than excluding them. That said, you can work around this limitation by first extracting the files to a temporary directory and then moving only the files you want to keep to the target directory. Alternatively, you can unzip each file individually by iterating through the entries in the zip file and only extracting the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I feared. I will just filter "by hand" as I process the files.